# Makerbot Smart extruder+ heat block and nozzle question

Tags: extruder, nozzle, makerbot

I am looking for information on the smart extruder+ heat block and nozzle?  I have looked online and from several forums come to the conclusion it is either a MK10 or MK11 assembly.  Can anyone shed some details on the heat block and nozzles.

Comment: This is probably their own design, not a MK10 or MK11. The heat block seems to have a coned extension leading up to the nozzle. Like Ultimaker, a crappy decision (I know as I have an UM3E) to sell those all in one (expensive!) cores (from the point of view from a tinkerer).

Comment: Thanks Oscar, being new to 3D printing this helped a bunch knowing I wasn't missing something or just didn't have the right search terms to the find the part.  As an engineer and tinkerer myself I just assumed they would make replacement parts or aftermarket parts like in most industries.  I am glad the replicator+ I got was free and it's a pretty decent machine.  I refuse to send the extruder back to MB every time I get a clog so I am going to buy a replacement and then modify the existing one.  When I purchase my next printer I will research how easy they are to modify!!! Thanks again

Comment: Maybe [this answer](/a/5437/5740) is of use to you, it shows history up to MK 11

Answer (score 1):

<sub>Caveat emptor: This answer is probably not what you're expecting.</sub>

As far as I can make out after looking at [this un-jamming video](https://youtu.be/I4vamb5LMqs?t=77) on YouTube, where at time 00:01:24, the video shows a label that needs to be cut to open up the extruder. However, as mentioned at the end of the same video, cutting that label will void Makerbot's warranty cover on the extruder.

From that, I can make out that Makerbot will actively discourage any efforts to disseminate the kind of information you're looking for, at least until the product is discontinued. That would usually include a [DMCA takedown notice](https://www.dmca.com/faq/What-is-a-DMCA-Takedown) to Google to remove search engine results, as well as similar takedown notices to other places where such information is hosted. I expect you will not find such information easily.

Comment: I'm not sure if this really answers the question... it doesn't seem to do so. However, it is related and interesting, and might serve better as two [sticky] comments (it won't fit in one).